# Prove that field of complex numbers cannot be equipped with an order relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please guide me in this problem. I am confused about whether its asking that having the relation $z>0$ does not satisfy the order axioms.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: squares are nonnegative in an [ordered field.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)

Comment: so you mean that if z = i (then z>0) but in this case the square of z is -1 which is <0. Would that be enough to prove the above?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you have proved said statement from the axioms that you are using.

Comment: you mean if I have proved that -1<0? Yes, i have already established that. Thanks!

Comment: No, I mean that you need to prove that squares are nonnegative using whatever ordered field axioms that you are using (there are at least several variations).

Comment: Well according to one of the axioms, $x.y\in P$ where $x,y\in P$ so if x = y then its quite obvious from this axiom that the squares are nonnegatives in ordered fields. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that works fine.

Answer (score 22):

What they are asking is to show that no relation $<$ can exist that complies with the order axioms, i.e.:

1. Only one of $a < b$, $a = b$, or $a > b$ is true
2. If $a < b$ and $b < c$, then $a < c$
3. If $a < b$ and $c < d$, then $a + c < b + d$
4. If $0 < a < b$ and $0 < c < d$, then $a c < b d$

In this case, if we take $i > 0$ we get $i^2 = -1 < 0$, contradicting (4). So by (1) it must be $i < 0$. But $i^4 = 1 > 0$, again contradicting (4). So no relation $<$ can exist on $\mathbb{C}$ which complies with (1) to (4).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have solved it by evoking the contradiction by letting $z=i$ and then stating that the square of z is $z.z =-1<0$ whereas squares must be nonnegative in ordered rings according to one of the order axioms (which says x.y∈P where x,y∈P so if x = y then its quite obvious from this axiom that the squares are nonnegatives in ordered fields)

Comment: @uh1, the same as mine with a shortcut. Great! But please close the issue accepting an answer (or providing your own, and accepting that).

Comment: it is not true that: if a < b and c < d then ac < bd a = -10, b = -8, c = -6, d < -4: (-10)(-6) < (-8)(-4), 60 < 32 CLEARLY FALSE

Comment: user75388 The < operator should change sign to > IF multiplied by negative numbers (also in this case).

Comment: The fourth axiom should be
$\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ ,if $ a<b$ and $0<c$ then $ac<bc$.

Answer (score 0):

try z = i the square root of -1 for a simple contradiction.