# Well ordered and ordered set

Tags: real-analysis

What does it mean for a set to be well ordered or ordered? Is there a connection between a well-ordered set and an ordered set ? If there is, then can one be derived from the other? Or if there is no connection then what is the difference between them.

Comment: Are the integers ordered? well-ordered?  Are the naturals ordered? well-ordered?

Comment: Well ordered is a subset of ordered which also includes partially ordered, cyclic orders etc etc.

Comment: Have tried looking at the definitions in the Wikipedia?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already understand what an order relationship means:

Let $S$ be an ordered set. We say that $S$ is well-ordered if, and only if, $\forall A \subseteq S, A \neq \emptyset, \exists x\in A$ such that $x=min(A)$

If you try to check by yourself whether $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are well ordered sets, and get it right, you can say you understood the idea. It's pretty basic

Comment: So in that sense, the real numbers are ordered but not well ordered. On the other hand, the positive integers are both ordered and well ordered.

Comment: @AyanShah That's right!

Comment: Can you give me some insight as to why R^2 is ordered but C is not?

Comment: You can define order relationships in both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or any other set you want) When we say $\mathbb{C}$ is not ordered, we actually mean that no order relationship defined on $\mathbb{C}$  will have the same algebraic properties as the usual order relation in $\mathbb{R}$ Here's a proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312204/prove-that-field-of-complex-numbers-cannot-be-equipped-with-an-order-relation Anyway, I don't see why that is different than  $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: $\emptyset \subset S$